# Improving text drawing performance through caching

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am currently developing a 2d graphic engine for a game using the canvas element. In this engine, various sprites have text labels which follow them around. I did some profiling to improve performance and noticed that the largest FPS-eater in this engine are my calls to `context.fillText` and `contex.drawText` for drawing these text labels on every frame. I can understand that this is a performance-hook, because rasterizing vector-based TTF fonts isn't a trivial task. So I am searching for a way to improve this through caching the rendered texts.

**What I tried**

I though that to speed this up I could draw each text labels once, cache the result, and draw these cached results instead. So I tried to draw each text label to an invisible canvas the first time it is needed. But in order to do so I need to know the width and height of the rendered text so that I can create a background canvas with the appropriate size. I tried to get this with `context.measureText`, but unfortunately many browsers don't implement it fully (Firefox returns only the width, not the height or anything else).

Another thing I tried was to let the browsers HTML rendering engine handle the text caching. So instead of drawing the text labels with the canvas, I created HTML `<span>` elements with `position:absolute`, added them to the `<div>` the canvas is in, and moved these around every frame so that they were always where they needed to be. This sort of worked performance-wise, but it cause a whole bunch of other problems. Some can be worked around (text labels catching click events, text being drawn outside of the canvas) but others aren't fixable that easily (canvas being unable to draw over text). So I discarded this solution.

Do you have any ideas what else I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For caching the text, you can use a HTML element with `visibility: hidden` but not `display: none` (so that it sizes out to accommodate the contents) - measure out its computed width and height and use that to size your cache-source canvas. For your HTML element, specify the same font (using `@font-face`) and size etc.

You may want to do this after ensuring that the font specified in your `@font-face` declaration has loaded completely. `$(document).ready(..)` will *not* work reliably. It should be safe to do this inside `$(window).load(..)` which is fired only after *everything* including content and resources are loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to *offline* the text rendering inside a `setTimeout(...)` effectively letting the rest of the rendering continue smoothly.

Comment: And how is that supposed to fix my problem? I need to draw the text labels on every frame. They need to be drawn together with everything else on the scene.

Comment: But the delay i believe won't be *that* apparent if you use a 0 or a close-to-0 timeout value.

Comment: Also, there may be other items on screen that you can de-prioritize off the main rendering queue. The HUD, for example.

Comment: You don't really seem to understand the problem. Parallelization won't fix the problem that I currently render the exact same text again and again 60 times per second. Or rather I would like it to be 60 times per second, now it's more like 20 because all the font rendering takes so long. (btw: my HUD is not part of the canvas - it consists of HTML elements above it)

Comment: Ok, about caching the rendered text, have you tried rendering the same text with the same font and size on a (visibility: hidden) HTML element (with font-face); measuring out its calculated size and using that for creating the cache-source canvas.

Comment: No, I didn't. Might be worse a try, though. Could you post that as a new answer?

Comment: Posted. Actually did that (measuring dimensions using HTML elements and using the same elsewhere) once for a structured editor i was writing. :-)